# Decomposing a cycle into transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I am trying to go through some lecture notes found [here](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect1-AbstractGroupTheory-2019.pdf), and am struggling with an assertion on page 21. It is meant to be a proof that any cycle $(a_1,..,a_k)$ can be written as a product of transpositions.

We have the identity
$(1,k)(1,k-1)...(1,3)(1,2) = (1,2,...,k)$.

Now consider a permutation $\phi$ taking
$1 \rightarrow a_1, ..., k\rightarrow a_k$. Using the above identity, we can write

$(a_1,..,a_k) = \phi \circ(1,k)...(1,2)\circ \phi^{-1}$.

The claim is that this is our desired decomposition. We have not shown that $\phi$ itself can be written as transpositions, so how do I see that the right-hand-side of the above equation is indeed just some transpositions?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, we just have that
$$
\begin{split}
(a_1,..,a_k) &= \phi \circ(1,k)...(1,2)\circ \phi^{-1} \\
&= \phi \circ(1,k)\circ\phi^{-1} \circ \phi\circ(1,k-1)...(1,2)\circ \phi^{-1} \\
&= (a_1,a_k)(a_1,a_{k-1})...(a_1,a_2),
\end{split}
$$
giving the result.

Comment: For permutations, if $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ is a cycle, and $\phi$ is any permutation, then $\phi(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\phi^{-1} = (\phi(a_1),\ldots,\phi(a_k))$. So your expression is necessarily a product of transpositions, regardless of what "shape" $\phi$ has.

Comment: Ah ok, that's what I was missing, thanks! I just need to insert the identity between each term in the product, and then each term is obviously just a transposition.

Comment: $\phi$ simply acts as a way of renaming the elements. Why it wasn't just done as $(a_1, a_k)(a_1, a_{k-1})\dots (a_1, a_2)$ (which is the effect of it) I don't know.